# D7 Webform custom email template url encoding issue

Tags: webforms

I am a newbie in Drupal development, my current project use drupal webform module email functionality to send an email to the recipient and using the custom email template.

The email template has a href link that allows the user to share the tweet, I want to add the  custom tag in the middle of shared text, so I encode the # as %23 in the querystring, however when webform sends out the email, the %23 is always getting decoded, which breaks the tweet content.

Below is the original link I put in my email template

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=please%20test%20me%23beer">test share</a>
```

The following output is the decoded version I get from the email source

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=please%20test%20me#beer">test share</a>
```

Can someone advise me how to fix this annoying issue? if that's the webform bug, which hook or function I can use the prevent this decoding issue?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is more basic - # character is legal in URI, so webform may try to decode it. Maybe it should be a bugreport?

Comment: But why %20 is not getting decoded?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in module. Have you tried to trace it yourself?

Comment: As I said I am a newbie, I don't know which file I can trace this issue in web form module

Comment: Well, you can either file a bugreport to webform module, or you can open it's files in IDE (my personal preference is NetBeans), look for the place where you define mail template, look for the place where mail is actually sent, and examine everything between.

Comment: First thanks for your fast reply. I will log the bug, however I think you misunderstand part of my issue, I used webform built in custom email template , not create any custom php file at all. That's why I don't know which file should I debug,

Comment: No, I got you right. And I meant webform module php files. Something in them decodes %23 when it shouldn't - probably faulty condition in part that processes template before mail is sent.

Comment: If you found a solution, please post.

Comment: Now looking in to this a bit more, I think whatever is handling the email (browser, ticketing system, etc.) is de-encoding it and that it's not a problem with Webform.